# How can I control the list that shows when New Work Item is selected in Visual Studio using TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem, alm

I've added several new work item types to a team project in TFS, but when I go into Visual Studio and choose New Work Item they seem to be listed in a pretty haphazard order.  I'd like to group them together in some fashion, but I can't tell what is used to determine the item ordering and grouping.  Is there a way to control this?

I thought the Categories may be related, but they put Bugs right next to my Requirement category items and Task category items so it doesn't seem like they are.

Comment: I'm looking at tfs 2010 (I don't have 2012 here at work atm) but it appears they are alphabetized. We have a few custom work items that aren't out of the box and they are being ordered by alphabet with everything else. I doubt (but you never know) that you can edit the sort order.

Comment: They're definitely not alphabetized in VS 2012 connected to TFS 2012 and they're not in order of creation, so I'm not really sure how they're organized at all.

Comment: I'll look at my TFS 2013 Express I have at home and see if I can figure out anything. I have a feeling this is not customizable though. In TFS 2010 it actually adds the most common work items you have used over the New menu so that may be their way of handling it (in 2010 anyways).

Comment: hi @Brian, can you please add a screenshot? I've tested here at tfs2013 and it is in alphabetizical order.